# Dojo hide button label inside TableContainer

Tags: javascript, dojo

Have a dojox.layout.TableContainer containing some text fields and buttons. However the labels of the buttons are displayed before the button and on the button. Below is a subset of the code some slight changes:

```
 var tableContainer = new dojox.layout.TableContainer(
                {
                    cols: 1
                });
var txtBox =  new dijit.form.TextBox({
                    id: "txtBox1",
                    name: "txtBox1",
                    label: "First TextBox:"
                },"ftxtb");
var addBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
                    label: "Add Button"
                });
tableContainer.addChild(txtBox);
tableContainer.addChild(addBtn);
```

Now labels for TextBoxes are OK but I don't want the button label to be displayed except on the button. To clarify button will be shown as:

```
Add Button    <Add Button>
```

How can I hide the label outside the button?

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/PnNSw/) displays your code just fine with only a label on the button. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Additionally, I don't think the `label` property works like you think it does for `dijit.form.TextBox`. You need to create a separate `label` element and place it on the DOM.

Comment: Funny enough my code shows the labels for both textbox and button and that's what is mentioned on the dojo documentation.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. Look at my jsfiddle; the `dijit/Button` code is exactly the same as yours. Can you provide a link to the documentation that you mentioned?

Comment: Here's the link to the TableContainer:
[link](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/TableContainer.html)

Or maybe I should put the button outside. Anyway I got rid of the TableContainer as I can't tell what really is the problem and now using dojo create label.

Comment: If you're still trying to track down the issue (and to help others who have the same problem in the future), maybe you should paste the HTML you're using, too. That might clear up some confusion.

Comment: Am doing everything programmatically and loading it inside a dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the button widget inside a ContentPane and then place the ContentPane inside TableContainer the problem goes away. I ran into exact same problem and I was also building everything programmatically inside a Dialog widget.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out later and get back to you.

Comment: Yes. Because the CSS applied works that way. The hierarchy must be a valid one if the CSS must apply properly. TabContainer -> ContentPane (0...1) --> in each ContentPane --> text/widgets etc.. TabContainer can contain only Pane objects, which will hold anything, as seen as content for that particular tab resp.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post but I just found that using spanLabel:true with your button hides that extra label displayed in UI. Hope this helps.

Comment: this should be the top answer. No one would want to add extra content panes.